# Sublime Text 3 - highlight hyperlinks

Tags: sublimetext3

I am completely new to Sublime text 3 and at the moment only want to use it to work with normal text files (no source code), containing a lot of URLs.

At first, I tried Sublime Text 2 which would be pretty good for what I want because with "plain text" syntax it automatically highlights links in red. For ST3 I tried for hours to get this to work, but for every syntax I tried there are some characters (like " and ') that screw up my document (e.g. highlight half of it because there is a single ' somewhere in it).

All I would like is a different color for URLs. How can I do this? And how can I set this to be the default, so that it stays that way when I restart ST3?

Comment: there's a package that underlines URLs which you could modify to color them: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Clickable%20URLs

Comment: Yes, I have seen that package. But I am completely new to ST3 and have no idea how to modify it. And spending a lot of time on just this one thing -how to have URLs highlighted - is not worth it to me. I guess, I will try another editor or ST2.